# Find a bijection

Tags: functions

I want to find a bijection between $A$ and $B$, where 
$$A=[0,1) \times [0,1)$$
$$B = \{ \langle x,y \rangle \in \mathbb{R}^2: x,y \ge 0, x+y<1 \}$$
Graphing $B$, we get a triangle with an area equal to ${1 \over 2}$. My first idea is to use the area and write down the function as $f(x,y)={x+y \over 2}$. This, however, is not an injection (by extension, not a bijection). Is there an obvious way to come up with a bijective transformation here?

Comment: Let f:B->A; f(x,y) = (x,y/(1-x)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between $A$ and $B$ is that when we choice an $(x,y) \in B$, $x$ may be anything in $[0,1)$ but $y$ can only be in $[0, 1-x)$.  But once we fix $x$ $[0,1-x) \leftarrow\rightarrow [0,1)$ via $y \rightarrow \frac y{1-x}$.

So simply do $f:B\rightarrow A$ via $f(x,y) = (x, \frac y{1-x})$.

....or $g:A\rightarrow B $ via $g (x,y)=(x, y(1-x)) $.

Comment: Sorry, isn't this wrong?  In particular, with your $f$ as shown, $f(.99,.5) = (.99,50)$ which is outside of region $B$.  What am I missing, if anything?

Comment: Oops, a made a typo.  f maps B to A.  So (.99, .5) is not in B.  But f (.99, .009)= (.99,.9) is in A.

Comment: $f^{-1}(.99, .5)=(.99,.005) $ is in the realm of B.

Answer (score 1):

The following mapping function defines a continuous bijection between $A$ and $B$:

$$
(x,y)_A \mapsto \left\{ \begin{array}{cl} (0,0)_B & x=y=0\\
\left( \frac{x^2}{x+y}, \frac{xy}{x+y}\right)_B & x\leq y ,(x,y) \neq (0,0) 
\\ \left( \frac{xy}{x+y}, \frac{y^2}{x+y}\right)_B & y>x  \end{array}\right. 
$$

The motivation for that form is that you can map each ray at an angle $\theta$ from the origin in region $A$ into a corresponding ray at the same angle but scaled such that the intersection of the ray with whichever of $x=1$ or $y=1$ it hits first, is mapped to the intersection of the ray with $y=1-x$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Consider $$(x,y)\to \begin{cases}(0,0), & (x,y)=(0,0)\\ \dfrac{\max\{x,y\}}{x+y}(x,y), & (x,y)\ne (0,0).\end{cases}$$

Comment: Um.  (x/(x+y),y/(x+y) is not in B and as x/(x+y) + y(x+y) = 1 which is not less than 1.

Comment: @fleablood Mistake fixed. We have to divide by $\|\|_1$ and multiply by $\|\|_{\infty}.$